Is there a language that is recursive and not within the set of context-sensitive languages?
Let me explain, it has been seen that recursive languages are more than context-sensitive but less than recursively enumerable languages.
I would like an example of a language that does not belong to the context-dependent ones (so there is not a LBA that recognizes its words), but is recursive (so there is a TM that halts for all input strings).
If the example is too abstract, at least have a formal proof that such a language can exist.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language#Examples or the bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language#Examples

@NaïmFavier Thanks, do you know how to prove that a language is recognizable for a LBA?

One obvious way is to construct an LBA that recognises it.

It is known that the class of context-sensitive languages is exactly $\mathsf{NSPACE}(O(n))$, i.e., languages which can be recognized in linear space by a non-deterministic Turing machine. By the space hierarchy theorem, any problem complete for $\mathsf{NSPACE}(O(f(n)))$, where $f$ is a space-constructible function satisfying $n = o(f(n))$, is decidable (= recursive) but not context-sensitive. For example, take any problem hard for NEXPSPACE, which equals EXPSPACE by Savitch's theorem. This cstheory.stackexchange.com answer has examples of EXSPACE-hard problems.
